# Android: getResources().getIdentifier(...) does not work for SOME drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable

I use

```
int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

to retrieve the id of a `drawable` resource. 
It works fine for some of my images in the list, but for others it sets `icon` to 0 instead of the respective id. I checked if the files exist and are named correctly. The debug mode shows that the desired string element can be found and is correctly written in `filename`.
The `drawables` that make trouble were added later than the ones working fine. Though I cleaned the project, refreshed, deleted and installed from phone...

I do not understand what the problem could be. Does anyone have a hint how I can find a solution? Thank you.

Comment: sure, first thing I did was to clean the project :)

Comment: What kind of resources are the new ones? Are they in the drawable folder or in raw (or in assets)?

Comment: .png (as the old ones) in the drawable folders

Comment: Try a clean build. The refresh (assuming Eclipse) won't necessarily force a recompile for a resource change.

Comment: I'm assuming that all file names use small caps, or R won't even compile...

Comment: correct. all in small caps, no specials

Comment: So, it's really weird. It MUST work. One last experiment: try replacing `this.getPackageName()` with `getApplicationContext()` in the instruction shown in your question.

Comment: still the same. it works for the first 6 elements, and no.7 leaves icon with 0

Comment: and btw, if i enter the string directly (manually), it works!

Comment: oh wow, i found the mistake: filename = "abc", but [a, b, c, ]... no idea what position [3] is, how it got there and how i can get rid of it. but the problem is in my database. phew...